# How to get time from date including the "0" in Minutes?

Tags: swift, string, time, timestamp, nsdate

I am using this method for getting the time in my application:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

timeStamp = ("\"\(hour):\(minutes)\"")
dateFull = ("\"\(day)/\(month)/\(year)\"")

print(dateFull)
print(timeStamp)
```

When I print out timeStamp it gives me some strange values when the "Minutes" is below 10 past the hour e.g instead of "9:03" it will print "9:3" etc. It doesn't include the 0 before the digit. Any way around this using my current method?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe make use of [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/288-datecomponentsformatter-basics) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func convertDateToHourMin(date : Date) -> String{
        let calender = Calendar.current
        let components = calender.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,], from: date)
        var hour = String(components.hour!)
        var minute = String(components.minute!)

        if hour.count == 1{
            hour = "0\(hour)"
        }

        if minute.count == 1{
            minute = "0\(minute)"
        }

        return "\(hour)\(minute)"
}
```

or you can also write like this.

```
func convertDateToHourMin(date : Date) -> String{
    let calender = Calendar.current
    let components = calender.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,], from: date)
    let dateInString  = String(format: "%02d:%02d", Int(components.hour!) , Int(components.minute!))
    return dateInString
}
```

Comment: How quickly we forget ... most of the formatting code could be reduced to a single line using something like `String(format: "%02d:%02d", hour, minute)` - but I'd still us a `DateComponentsFormatter`

Comment: Thanks for all the guidance, this was the solution I used and it works well!

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: @LukeIreton No problem. Glad to help you :)